# Can not insert french string in database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have form with input text, when i add text
 `Un sac à main de femme recèlerait une quantité importante de bactéries`

it adds in database only `Un sac`

i have tried with addslashes, mysql_real_escape_string, htmlspecialchars etc. also using UTF-8 encoding, but still it can not insert whole string

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: what is db field length?

Comment: What encoding is you original string in. That is within the code.

Comment: what collation have you used in column you are adding french string in.. ?

Comment: try htmlentities() or check your database default collation

Comment: yes, htmlentitie() worked. .

Comment: I hope this link can give you more ... http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Answer (score 2):

YOu should use `utf8_unicode_ci` as your column's collation in orer for French strings to be added in it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to store non-US strings in the database, you must ensure that each of the following 3 steps are correctly implemented:

1. You **database table** must be set to a charset compatible with French. To be future proof, I recommend creating tables with UTF-8. For more information see the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html).
2. Your **database connection** must be set to a proper character set both when storing and when querying. To do this, use [`mysqli_set_charset()`](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset) (or whatever your MySQL connector offers).
3. Your input form AND your view page must be **served with the exact character set** as your data. To do that, you will need to set the following header: [`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`](http://php.net/header) (If you are using a different charset, change it accordingly.)

You can of course use a different character set for storage and representation but why would you want to do that?

Also, when working with databases and HTML, you should consider:

1. ALWAYS **escape your data** as it goes **into the database**. Use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) or whatever escape method your database connector offers. Also, do NOT set the connection charset by using `SET NAMES UTF8`, otherwise your connector library will not know what charset to use for escaping. For more information [google "sql injection"](http://www.google.com/?q=sql%20injection).
2. ALWAYS **escape your data** as it goes **into HTML** with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Also pay attention to ALWAYS provide the correct character set. For more information [google "xss"](https://www.google.com/?q=xss).

Answer (score 1):

After breaking my head for 2 days straight and reading all the possible answers here's what solved the problem and allows me to insert additional weird characters like em dash etc. and retrieve data without seeing weird characters.

> Here's the complete step-by-step setup.

**The collation of the db column need to be: utf8_general_ci**

**The type is: varchar(250)**

[image]

**In the PHP header set the default client character set to UTF8**

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $link);
```

**Set the character set result so we can show french characters**

```
$sql = "SET character_set_results=utf8";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**In the html header specify, so you can view the french characters:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**When inserting the data do NOT use utf8_decode, just the below will work fine**

```
$query = 'insert into tbl (col) VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($variable).'");
```

**Use normal queries to retreive data, example query:**

```
$query = "select * from table;";
```

Finally got this fixed, hope this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

In the php:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

After connection:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up with this, I was using dbForge Studio and just pasting in French text and I had all the collations/encoding set properly. The one thing I didn't have set was the actual encoding for the connection to the db. Set it to `UTF8` and all was well again. #2 in @Janoszen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The input text came from ANSII file, so it wasn't quite UTF8, despite all my utf8 settings. utf8_encode(input_text) solved it.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried

> htmlentities()

. .it saves the string as it is in the database

Comment: Storing the text encoded with htmlentities() means that you can ONLY output it to HTML and ONLY in the character set it has been encoded in. The proper way to do it is to set the MySQL tables and connections to a character set that can represent French characters.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this to insert special character in mysql :

```
$con = mysql_connect($server,$uname,$pass);
$res = mysql_select_db($database,$con)

mysql_set_charset("letin1", $con);
```

Comment: Warning ! mysql_* functions are deprecated and dangerous.